# Can Typescript infer the specific sub-type of a tagged union, based on a given tag value?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have an object of type `Foo`, which has a member `bar: Bar`. `Bar` is a tagged union, which I have defined as

```
type ABar = {name: 'A', aData: string};
type BBar = {name: 'B', bData: string};
type Bar = ABar | BBar;
type BarName = Bar['name']; // this is equivalent to 'A'|'B'
```

Different parts of my code want to process `foo.bar` only if it has a particular type; i.e. some parts only care if the `bar` is an `ABar`, others only care if the `bar` is a `BBar`. I'd like to define a function that extracts the Bar from a Foo in a type safe way. What I have so far is a function:

```
function getBar(foo: Foo, name: BarName): Bar | null {
    return foo.bar.name === name ? foo.bar : null;
}
```

This works, but the caller has to explicitly assert the correct type, i.e.

```
let aBar = getBar(foo, 'A') as ABar | null;
```

Is there any way to get the TS compiler to infer that if the given name is 'A', then the result must indeed have type `ABar` (or null)?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICCAhAhgJ3gXngbwHaoC2sAXPAOSIUA08qAIquKuQM7joCW+A5gL4BuCDATI0mHAWJlKyWvABGTFu048BwkFDjwJ2JPoA+eiVp1iMAORkGJAbQqESFALqD4Aek-xwACy42eED4WABHAFcuADdUABtYfHBfAHtKaiMKeVARXQAxFLSpRQxyCSEckAAzCPwAY3AuFPx4XlhwCQAKKsLyApS6Z1kJGxIASjKMeBN8CLi4vFB4Zfh0doj0Fp6UgDoS9B2h7CwcI4B+eG29qfJZ+a1+SoTk7b7Cg1x98mkScioFRjMViUNgpEjwAAmQIo-AqYHhz3o+hwbQ6GG6hTo-zGWm8wSC-lga3o8AA7qhIKl4HU-Kg+AhCfA2FxeIRwBsECkqq12vpQb5aeBQHiACoAZWpdOC+CqRIFzCRU1pBNEhimMzmC1AQA) is the same example in TS Playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the function generic and use the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type to extract a union member based on a given `name`.

```
function getBar<T extends BarName>(foo: Foo, name: T) {
    return (
      foo.bar.name === name ? foo.bar : null
    ) as Extract<Bar, { name: T }> | null;
}

let aBar = getBar(foo, 'A');
// let aBar: ABar | null

let bBar = getBar(foo, 'B');
// let bBar: BBar | null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICCAhAhgJ3gXngbwHaoC2sAXPAOSIUA08qAIquKuQM7joCW+A5gL4BuCDATI0mHAWJlKyWvABGTFu048BwkFDjwJ2JPoA+eiVp1iMAORkGJAbQqESFALqD4Aek-xwACy42eED4WABHAFcuADdUABtYfHBfAHtKaiMKeVARXQAxFLSpRQxyCSEcsBAAMwj8AGNwLhT8eF5YcAkAHgAVUIAPcESAEyCJGxIAPgAKasLyApS6Z1kegEo8UHht+HQOiPRW6a2d7bmUgDoS9AuV7CwcO4B+eHOrjHhyfAi4uJPtjaoIIAUUG6FQjS6EjouHgK3IfX4k3gJm+vy0-EqCWS5wWhQMuGu5GkJHIVAUjGYrEobBSJHgwypFH4FSqoGx9H0OHanQws0KdHJay03ngHNQEnIKA+qJ+fyqHMUXLaHQk-KWcgowtAosVktMMrhctAQA)

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I was hoping for, and a good reason to be familiar with the utility type constructors.

It looks like the Playground link you shared is broken. Fix it and I'll accept the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, it's worth noting that TypeScript will infer the correct type of `Bar` if you check the `name` property as part of an `if` statement:

```
if (bar.name === "A") {
  bar.aData; // No error, bar has type "ABar" here.
}
```

This might be good enough depending on how your code is structured. If you still want to use the `getBar` function though, you might be able to use one of these approaches:

---

Option one, you could use another type that associates each of the `Bar` types to it's name. Eg:

```
type BarMap = {
  A: ABar;
  B: BBar;
}
```

This makes looking up the correct associated type, given the name, very straightforward if you use a generic function:

```
function getBar<T extends BarName>(foo: Foo, name: T): BarMap[T] {
  // @ts-ignore: SMH TypeScript, this works fine.
  return foo.bar.name === name ? foo.bar : null;
}
```

Unfortunately this creates a nasty error message on the return line, but ultimately I would just ignore that error since this will work fine at runtime and it achieves the correct inference:

```
let aBar = getBar(foo, 'A'); // Type: ABar | null
let bBar = getBar(foo, 'B'); // Type: BBar | null
```

If you try and pass it a name that is not part of the `BarName` type, it will produce an error:

```
let cBar = getBar(foo, 'C') // Error: Argument of type '"C"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B"'
```

---

Option two is to use an overload signature on your function, which will allow you to specify the exact return type for each parameter combination. Eg:

```
function getBar(foo: Foo, name: 'A'): ABar | null;
function getBar(foo: Foo, name: 'B'): BBar | null;
function getBar(foo: Foo, name: BarName): Bar | null {
  return foo.bar.name === name ? foo.bar : null;
}
```

This also achieves the same inference and will also produce an error if you pass a non-valid `name`. If you wanted to, you could also add another signature to the overload to set the return type to a bare `null` for unknown keys.

Depending on your use case, you may find one of these solutions to be more maintainable than the other.

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICCAhAhgJ3gXngbwHaoC2sAXPAOSIUA08qAIquKuQM7joCW+A5gL4BuCDATI0mHAWJlKyWvABGTFu048BwkFDjwJ2JPoA+eiVp1iMAORkGJAbQqESFALqD4Aek-xwACy42eED4WABHAFcuADdUABtYfHBfAHtKaiMKeVARXQAxFLSpRQxyCSEc7VE9DABZVGgDXFB4JHIUDC1W5DKzUH5KgDMI-ABjcC4U-HheWHAJAApBwvIClLpnWQkbEgBKMox4E3wIuLi8Ftb4dDmI9GnllIA6EvQnzewsHA+AfnhHl6HcgnM5aAZgEDDMYTKYzOYSADiiVg3FGAB4ACqhAAe4ESABMgtsZAA+JYreBrDYycgY-Y1dD1aD2DGuI7wEHnZogK5eHwAAXAbAAtFxePgUjdyAB1SUAayCgx4sCeqsurRu4DuD0KgLeHy+31sfwBr3gwNOcTBQxG40m01m8wwSPwKK4oysKSZmJxePwhIZO1gZMeq0K1JItPpC30ADI8JtafxduzORceVdvPBBSKxRKpfBZegFf9laqnurrrd7v9da93rZDRzjbXnmaLaD+jbofa4U70AB5aIouIpVD48kpMPrZuR9IUekdTDHS1aKF22GOiRDkdjiehynh2eyLIL3qHFedyG2mEO+EYHfoUfjyfTiNbawyenGDmW9O8zVtVbPUGxIT4jTAk06yBX8r3BUAEmSA81iaV5yGkOcqAURhmFYSg2BSMD8Vwih+AqCEELmeh9BwLdnWRVFJzoLDdi0RClBovtEQY90mLkBc2Ko0ZOLo9AXTdUY+IoABhATQCzEJ-BRBBUHgAB3VBIFSeBRj8VA+AQJT4DYPNmDuBAUkGLjDgI3w9PAeSfAxABlHT9OCfBBhROzmGow49KCCxDAvWDzlAIA)

Comment: I'll also note that if you want to use the generic function approach, but without the `BarMap` type, you can also intersect the return type with a type containing your name key. This will reduce all the non-matching parts of the union to `never`, leaving only the matched piece. This does, however, make the return type a little weird to look at: `function getBar<T extends BarName>(foo: Foo, name: T): (Bar & {name: T}) | null { ... }`, and if you hover `aBar`, you'll see it gets the type `(ABar & {name: "A"}) | null`.